# averaging first 5 data points every year

Tags: r, aggregate, mean

I am trying to average first 5 data points of "var1" every "year". My data is like as below. Length of each yearly data is not the same.  Thanks a lot for your help! :)

```
    year    var1
    2010    1
    2010    2
    2010    3
    2010    4
    2010    2
    2010    4
    2009    2
    2009    3
    2009    4
    2009    1
    2009    3
    2009    4
    2009    2
    2009    5
    2009    3
    2009    6
    2008    4
    2008    2
    2008    3
    2008    4
    2008    1
    2008    3
```

Comment: Did you search and research as in http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? There are lots of questions like this already answered for R

Comment: Also put down what answer you expect for 2008 and 2009, as this answer will vary dependent on how the data is sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted Average by Year in ragged data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30240023/weighted-average-by-year-in-ragged-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
t <- read.csv("t.txt", sep="") ## Read data
myMean <- function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5]))
ans <- aggregate(var1 ~ year, data = t, FUN = myMean)
ans
  year var1
1 2008   14
2 2009   13
3 2010   12
```

We create a function `myMean` to compute the mean of first 5 elements of a given vector.
For the `ifelse`, just in case, if some years do not have 5 data points, then we take the mean the all the data points.

We use the function `aggregate` to partition the data set by `year`. For each `year`, we apply the function `myMean` on `var1`.

Comment: I like this answer, assuming what OP wanted, because it accounts for cases where less than 5 cases may be available.

Comment: This simple code is great, extactly what I want!  Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

With data.table, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'year', we get the first 5 values of 'var1' (with `head`) and get the `mean`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(var1=mean(head(var1,5))), year]
#   year var1
#1: 2010  2.4
#2: 2009  2.6
#3: 2008  2.8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Akrun for your suggestions. Code below would be great to test and study for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option, using `split` and `lapply`:

```
sapply( split(X$var1,X$year), function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5])) )
```

where `X` is the given dataframe.

Speed comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

X <- read.table( header = TRUE,
                 text = "year    var1
                    2011    3
                    2011    8
                    2010    1
                    2010    2
                    2010    3
                    2010    4
                    2010    2
                    2010    4
                    2009    2
                    2009    3
                    2009    4
                    2009    1
                    2009    3
                    2009    4
                    2009    2
                    2009    5
                    2009    3
                    2009    6
                    2008    4
                    2008    2
                    2008    3
                    2008    4
                    2008    1
                    2008    3" )

myMean <- function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5]))

microbenchmark(
  akrun    = setDT(X)[, list(var1=mean(head(var1,5))), year],
  PoChoi.1 = aggregate(var1 ~ year, data = X, FUN = myMean),
  PoChoi.2 = aggregate(var1 ~ year, data = X, FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5]))),
  mra68.1  = sapply( split(X$var1,X$year), myMean ),
  mra68.2  = sapply( split(X$var1,X$year), function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5])) ),
  times = 1000
)

# Unit: microseconds
#    expr      min        lq      mean   median       uq        max neval
#    akrun 1781.673 3571.9520 3747.1294 3772.582 3931.320 147014.295  1000
# PoChoi.1 2273.966 4563.1035 4498.3682 4739.505 4982.933   9535.620  1000
# PoChoi.2 2289.817 4571.2555 4515.6098 4733.391 4956.892  21497.376  1000
#  mra68.1  347.368  693.8295  711.6527  731.420  769.462   5615.848  1000
#  mra68.2  346.915  694.7350  717.4941  730.740  772.633   5560.143  1000
```

`akrun` is a data table, `PoChoi` a dataframe, `mra68` a named vector:

```
> akrun
   year var1
1: 2011  5.5
2: 2010  2.4
3: 2009  2.6
4: 2008  2.8
> PoChoi.1
  year var1
1 2008  2.8
2 2009  2.6
3 2010  2.4
4 2011  5.5
> PoChoi.2
  year var1
1 2008  2.8
2 2009  2.6
3 2010  2.4
4 2011  5.5
> mra68.1
2008 2009 2010 2011 
 2.8  2.6  2.4  5.5 
> mra68.2
2008 2009 2010 2011 
 2.8  2.6  2.4  5.5
```

A larger example:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

X <- data.frame( year = sample( 1500:2015, 10000, replace=TRUE ),
                 var1 = sample( 1:10, 10000, replace=TRUE ) )

myMean <- function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5]))

microbenchmark(
  akrun    = setDT(X)[, list(var1=mean(head(var1,5))), year],
  PoChoi.1 = aggregate(var1 ~ year, data = X, FUN = myMean),
  PoChoi.2 = aggregate(var1 ~ year, data = X, FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5]))),
  mra68.1  = sapply( split(X$var1,X$year), myMean ),
  mra68.2  = sapply( split(X$var1,X$year), function(x) ifelse(length(x)<5, mean(x), mean(x[1:5])) ),
  times = 1000
)

# Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# akrun    15.44811 23.50436 36.81674 43.12405 44.22435  69.62202  1000
# PoChoi.1 33.96411 51.52858 83.29682 95.53486 99.60884 241.59967  1000
# PoChoi.2 33.64844 51.70747 83.47835 95.07223 99.44127 247.55881  1000
# mra68.1  11.05145 17.33191 27.21526 31.41954 32.34819 126.89461  1000
# mra68.2  11.05054 17.16615 26.96236 31.25061 32.14054  85.44422  1000
```

Except for the different classes ( data.table, data.frame, named vector ), the results are equal:

```
> all( PoChoi.1 == PoChoi.2 )
[1] TRUE

> all( PoChoi.1$var1 == mra68.1 )
[1] TRUE

> all( mra68.1 == mra68.2 )
[1] TRUE

> all( akrun$var1[order(akrun$year)] == mra68.1 )
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: Using `aggregate` with the formula `var1 ~ year` looks more intuitive to new R users, but, from your comparison, its downside is the slower speed.